# How do I use pandas DataFrame.style?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I am trying to format my dataframe in HTML using the [newly included 'style'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) in Pandas 0.19. I am trying to replicate the same things using the exact same scripts but I get a `Styler` object.

```
>>> df
              Security       Price  Change Percentage  ChgNetValue  LastClose
10     Japan Five-Year   -0.207000          -4.020000    -0.008000  -0.199000
13        U.S. 10-Year   97.406250        5274.434452    95.593850   1.812500
20        U.S. 30-Year   93.156250        3481.253980    90.555031   2.601562
23      U.S. 3M T-Bill    0.355000          -2.068966    -0.007500   0.362500
31      U.S. Five-Year  100.015625        7803.952347    98.750237   1.265625
36  Eurozone Five-Year   -0.423000          -3.171000    -0.013000  -0.410000
43       U.S. Two-Year   99.898438       12271.036276    99.090919  25.875000
44      U.K. Five-Year    0.529000          -3.114000    -0.017000   0.546000    
>>> df.style
    <pandas.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0000000008133F28>
>>> s = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
>>> s
    <pandas.formats.style.Styler object at 0x00000000035116A0>
```

I have the exact same function, `color_negative_red`, as in the documentation. I am doing this in Eclipse, not IPython.

What I want is to use `to_html()` and apply conditional formatting to each number in the dataframe. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the note below `Out [2]` [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/style.html#Building-Styles). `Styler` objects define a `_repr_html_` which renders the HTML in the notebook.

To get the actual HTML string, you call `styler.render()`.

Comment: After getting the HTML string do you just have to save the string and open it from there?