# Pandas: Get cells updated by pandas.DataFrame.update

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using `pandas.DataFrame.update` to merge two Dataframes like

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 103],
     'A': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'B': ['..', '..', '..'], 
}).set_index('ID')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 223],
     'A': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'B': ['..', 'XY', '..'],
}).set_index('ID')

df1.update(df2)
```

How can I get the cells (in this case column B of ID 102) e.g. to apply some formatting? My goal is to mark all cells which have been updated with a yellow background.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is compare original `df11` DataFrame with updated in custom function and pass to [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 103],
     'A': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'B': ['..', '..', '..'], 
}).set_index('ID')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [101, 102, 223],
     'A': ['..', '..', '..'],
     'B': ['..', 'XY', '..'],
}).set_index('ID')


df11 = df1.reset_index().copy()
df1.update(df2)


def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    df3 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df3 = df3.mask(df11.ne(x), c1)
    return df3

df1.reset_index().style.apply(highlight, axis=None).to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I can run the code without any errors but there is no yellow background in the HTML output...

Comment: @maxiw46 - do you run code in Jupiter notebook? Or do you use [`render`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421893/how-do-i-use-pandas-dataframe-style)  like `df1.reset_index().style.apply(highlight, axis=None).render()`?

Comment: I was using `.to_html()` for df1. But even when I print `df3` it's empty. Hence, I think there might be some issue with comparing the two DFs... Anyways, in the end my goal is to export it to excel with the formatting applied...

Comment: @jezrael there's a small typo in your code (`df11` vs. `df1`) apart from that, the code works fine in Jupyter for me.

Comment: @Moritz - Do you think `df11.ne(x)` ?

Comment: sorry, yours is named `df11` on top, I used `df1`. ignore please.

Comment: @maxiw46 - Tested ans working very well  for me with sample data

Comment: @jezrael Got it. However, only the cell in column ID is now marked yellow. My goal is to highlight each and every cell that has been changed. In this case the one in column B.

Comment: @maxiw46 - Oki, answer was edited, only function `highlight`